# How to fetch Planner plans and tasks using Python and MS Graph

Tags: python, rest, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I followed the python-sample-send-mail example from MS Graph (https://github.com/microsoftgraph/python-sample-send-mail) and it worked perfectly fine for me.
Then I modified it very slightly so that original functionality would still work and added new app-route to see what this call will return to me:

```
all_plans= MSGRAPH.get("me/planner/plans", headers=request_headers()).data
```

It turns out I don't have permissions to do that:

```
{
'error': {
  'code': '',
  'message': 'You do not have the required permissions to access this item.',
  'innerError': {
    'request-id': '4722fe32-425d-462d-a6b4-b5af4582b8cf',
    'date': '2018-05-04T21:46:31'}}}
```

I checked the APP permissions from here: https://apps.dev.microsoft.com
[image]
So it's clearly looks like I've got all my permissions set according to this document: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/plannerplan_get

Given all of that I'm completely lost and don't understand what should be done in order to make it work.

**Would really appreciate for any help and/or suggestions.**
Thanks in Advance!

## UPDATE [04 May 2018]

I guess the admin of the company should grant permission for this up to access MS-GRAPH Groups API... Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use scopes such as `Group.Read.All` or `Group.ReadWrite.All`, you need to receive Admin Consent from a tenant's admin. I wrote an article that walks through this that you might find helpful: [v2 Endpoint & Admin Consent](https://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-admin-consent/).

It's also worth noting that you're requesting *both* `Group.Read.All` and `Group.ReadWrite.All`. You should only be requesting one of these two scopes. If you truly only need `Read` access, you should only request `Group.Read.All`. If you need both `Read` and `Write` access, you should request only `Group.ReadWrite.All`.

You're also requesting both Delegated and Application scopes. Unless you're using the Client Credentials grant, you shouldn't have any Application scopes defined. Only delegated scopes are used for Authorization Code and Implicit OAuth grants.

Comment: Thank you, Marc. I really appreciate your reply. Admin Consent is under investigation now. I used both permissions since I thought that I'm doing something wrong and one is not enough. I knew that only Delegated is needed - but again were not sure - so selected Application scope as well. Will work with my company admin to see if I can grant permission. Thanks.